# How well does SQL Server typed xml scale with a very large number of schemas?

Tags: xml, sql-server-2012

I am working on an application that has user-defined data structures as a core part of its functionality. I am going to use a hybrid approach and store a decent amount of user data in XML within the database.

The structure of the XML will be user defined and the schema will be enforced (either by database or by code). If I enforce the xml schema in the database this will result in an arbitrarily large set of XML schemas applicable to the column. Is this horrible practice? Can this sort of setup scale as more schemas are added or am I better off doing this in code?

Thanks!